# How to get value from form and redirect to /value in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I need to get value from  tag and redirect to '/value/' by submit.

Now I'm getting:

```
'ApartmentForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

I'm totally missing something.

forms.py

```
class ApartmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        fields = ['title']
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    context['apartments'] = get_list_or_404(Apartment)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApartmentForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {'form': form,}
        id = form.cleaned_data.get('id', None)
        return redirect(id)
    else:
        context['apartment_form'] = ApartmentForm
        return render(request, 'main/main.html', context)
```

template

```
<form action="/{{ apartment.id }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><select size="10">
    <option disabled>Chose apartment</option>
    {% for apartment in apartments %}
        <option value="{{ apartment.id }}">{{ apartment.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Chose">
</form>
```

**Update**

Thanks Daniel!
It was such a fail not to call form in the template. I fixed that, but it still passing `None` to url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/None). Can't figure out why.

view.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    context['apartments'] = get_list_or_404(Apartment)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApartmentForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            id = form.cleaned_data.get('id', None)
            return redirect(id)
    else:
        context['apartment_form'] = ApartmentForm
        return render(request, 'main/main.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
APARTMENTS = ()
for apartment in Apartment.objects.all():
    APARTMENTS += ((apartment.id, apartment.title),)

class ApartmentForm(Form):
    apartment = ChoiceField(label='', widget=Select, choices=APARTMENTS)
```

template

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ apartment_form }}
<input type="submit" value="Chose">
```

Comment: You need to check `form.is_valid()`  before you can access cleaned_data.

Comment: Note also your form action value makes no sense; you don't have a value for apartment.id at that point. Luckily, that just makes the action empty, so it submits to the index view which is what you want anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, changed it to `action="."` and added `form.is_valid()` but now i'm getting ValueError says it returned None...
Traceback is below Lee's answer.

Comment: So, what are you returning if the form is not valid? Really, the pattern for form views is given in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view), there's not really a good reason for doing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.cleaned_data` comes from `form.is_valid()`, so you sould change your `views.py` like this:

```
def index(request):
    [...]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ApartmentForm(request.POST or None)
                if form.is_valid():
                    [...]
                    id = form.cleaned_data.get('id', None)
                    return redirect(id)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leonidivanov/Develop/A3/Standart/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/leonidivanov/Develop/A3/Standart/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view main.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Django's `view` should return HttpRespone Object.
However, if you get `None`, it would be from `id = form.cleaned_data.get('id',None)`. It means you didn't get `id` named input value from your form.

Comment: Yeah, problem was it had to be `id = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment',None)` in that case. Thanks guys!